# Remove values when reading a csv and return to a list

Tags: python, list, csv, formatting

I have a csv file of subjects XY Coordinates. Some XY's have been removed if the X-Coordinate is less than 5. This can be for any player and changes over time. (See example dataset).

At the start of this file P2, P7, P12, P17 have removed data. Although, throughout the file each player will have data missing. for about 90% of the file there will be at least 4 players having missing data at any time point.

```
Frame Time  P1_X    P2_Y  P2_X P2_Y P3_X    P3_Y    P4_X    P4_Y    P5_X    P5_Y    P6_X     P6_Y P7_X P7_Y P8_X    P8_Y    P9_X    P9_Y    P10_X   P10_Y   P11_X   P11_Y P12_X P12_Y 
0   10:39.2 65.75   45.10           73.74   -3.52   61.91   41.80   67.07   -24.62  77.14   -22.98          93.95   3.51    56.52   28.44   70.21   11.06   73.08   -35.54          69.79   45.73   73.34   29.26   64.73   -40.69  70.90   6.11            70.94   -45.11  42.78   3.00    61.77   -1.05   72.07   38.62
1   10:39.3 65.77   45.16           73.69   -3.35   61.70   41.79   67.19   -24.59  77.17   -23.03          93.90   3.53    56.54   28.38   70.20   11.00   73.15   -35.48          69.79   45.86   73.20   29.30   64.96   -40.77  70.91   6.10            71.04   -45.29  42.84   3.02    61.82   -0.99   72.12   38.71
2   10:39.4 65.78   45.24           73.63   -3.17   61.70   41.79   67.32   -24.56  77.20   -23.05          93.83   3.55    56.59   28.31   70.20   10.92   73.20   -35.41          69.79   45.86   73.03   29.36   65.19   -40.84  70.91   6.10            71.15   -45.50  42.91   3.04    61.89   -0.91   72.16   38.80
3   10:39.5 65.78   45.33           73.57   -3.00   61.49   41.78   67.45   -24.50  77.25   -23.07          93.75   3.57    56.59   28.31   70.21   10.83   73.25   -35.33          69.77   46.01   72.86   29.43   65.45   -40.86  70.90   6.09            71.15   -45.50  43.01   3.08    61.98   -0.81   72.19   38.86
4   10:39.6 65.78   45.33           73.51   -2.86   61.32   41.76   67.45   -24.50  77.31   -23.09          93.64   3.60    56.65   28.22   70.23   10.72   73.29   -35.22          69.72   46.17   72.69   29.51   65.75   -40.84  70.88   6.08            71.24   -45.71  43.11   3.12    62.06   -0.70   72.22   38.90
5   10:39.7 65.75   45.44           73.51   -2.86   61.20   41.73   67.59   -24.37  77.38   -23.10          93.52   3.63    56.73   28.09   70.25   10.59   73.29   -35.22          69.68   46.33   72.49   29.60   66.06   -40.84  70.86   6.05            71.31   -45.91  43.22   3.14    62.13   -0.59   72.26   38.92
6   10:39.8 65.72   45.56           73.45   -2.72   61.08   41.71   67.72   -24.19  77.44   -23.12          93.39   3.69    56.80   27.91   70.27   10.45   73.34   -35.08          69.66   46.48   72.27   29.67   66.36   -40.87  70.86   6.01            71.39   -46.09  43.35   3.17    62.20   -0.47   72.29   38.93
7   10:39.9 65.72   45.56           73.34   -2.48   60.97   41.72   67.92   -23.76  77.51   -23.13          93.23   3.75    56.80   27.91   70.30   10.31   73.40   -34.76          69.64   46.63   72.01   29.74   66.62   -40.93  70.85   5.96            71.39   -46.09  43.51   3.18    62.27   -0.35   72.31   38.93
8   10:40.0 65.73   45.90           73.34   -2.48   60.86   41.72   67.92   -23.76  77.51   -23.13          93.05   3.80    56.91   27.47   70.30   10.31   73.40   -34.76          69.63   46.76   72.01   29.74   66.82   -41.06  70.83   5.88            71.53   -46.45  43.68   3.20    62.27   -0.35   72.29   38.92
9   10:40.1 65.73   46.09           73.29   -2.39   60.74   41.70   68.00   -23.52  77.60   -23.12          92.83   3.86    56.99   27.23   70.35   10.17   73.43   -34.58          69.64   46.88   71.72   29.80   66.99   -41.22  70.80   5.79            71.60   -46.63  43.86   3.23    62.34   -0.22   72.22   38.89
10  10:40.2 65.76   46.27           73.22   -2.32   60.60   41.65   68.07   -23.24  77.71   -23.05          92.83   3.86    57.14   26.98   70.43   10.05   73.47   -34.38          69.68   46.96   71.42   29.85   67.16   -41.38  70.77   5.70            71.64   -46.80  44.04   3.28    62.43   -0.08   72.13   38.86
11  10:40.3 65.81   46.43           73.12   -2.28   60.43   41.60   68.12   -22.93  77.83   -22.94          92.58   3.89    57.32   26.72   70.54   9.92    73.50   -34.16          69.75   46.99   71.08   29.89   67.16   -41.38  70.74   5.62            71.67   -46.96  44.21   3.33    62.54   0.09    72.03   38.84
12  10:40.4 65.87   46.58           72.98   -2.29   60.24   41.55   68.15   -22.57  77.94   -22.76          92.30   3.93    57.52   26.45   70.67   9.78    73.50   -33.91          69.85   47.00   70.72   29.91   67.31   -41.57  70.70   5.52            71.73   -47.15  44.37   3.40    62.66   0.24    72.03   38.84
13  10:40.5 65.91   46.69           72.80   -2.32   60.07   41.49   68.17   -22.18  78.01   -22.53          91.99   3.98    57.71   26.18   70.81   9.60    73.49   -33.68          69.97   47.03   70.33   29.92   67.45   -41.78  70.64   5.38            71.81   -47.35  44.37   3.40    62.80   0.40    71.96   38.81
14  10:40.6 65.94   46.80           72.60   -2.34   59.93   41.43   68.19   -21.77  78.05   -22.27          91.69   4.03    57.89   25.90   70.96   9.42    73.47   -33.47          70.10   47.09   69.93   29.93   67.54   -41.96  70.56   5.20            71.86   -47.53  44.54   3.50    62.98   0.58    71.91   38.77
15  10:40.7 65.95   46.93           72.36   -2.36   59.80   41.38   68.18   -21.32  78.08   -21.99          91.38   4.09    58.11   25.63   71.11   9.26    73.41   -33.26          70.24   47.15   69.50   29.91   67.58   -42.15  70.56   5.20            71.86   -47.69  44.54   3.50    63.16   0.77    71.91   38.77
16  10:40.8 65.93   47.09           72.10   -2.34   59.65   41.36   68.16   -20.86  78.11   -21.68          91.09   4.17    58.35   25.38   71.23   9.13    73.31   -33.05          70.38   47.20   69.07   29.84   67.56   -42.32  70.44   5.00            71.81   -47.84  45.00   3.79    63.34   0.97    71.80   38.60
17  10:40.9 65.92   47.23           71.85   -2.28   59.47   41.37   68.11   -20.41  78.11   -21.37          90.81   4.27    58.59   25.12   71.33   9.00    73.22   -32.84          70.52   47.26   68.63   29.75   67.47   -42.51  70.28   4.78            71.75   -47.97  45.26   3.94    63.52   1.14    71.73   38.46
```

Because there is missing data I tried to read the csv file as such. If I removed the `try: except:` function I received a `Type Error stating I couldn't convert string to float`.

```
 with open('NoBench.csv') as csvfile :    
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV :
        if n == 0 :
            n+=1
        try:
            visuals[0].append([float(row[3]),float(row[5]),float(row[7]),float(row[9]),float(row[11]),float(row[13]),float(row[15]),float(row[17]),float(row[19]),float(row[21]),float(row[23]),float(row[25]),float(row[27]),float(row[29]),float(row[31]),float(row[33]),float(row[35]),float(row[37]),float(row[39]),float(row[41]),float(row[43])])
            visuals[1].append([float(row[2]),float(row[4]),float(row[6]),float(row[8]),float(row[10]),float(row[12]),float(row[14]),float(row[16]),float(row[18]),float(row[20]),float(row[22]),float(row[24]),float(row[26]),float(row[28]),float(row[30]),float(row[32]),float(row[34]),float(row[36]),float(row[38]),float(row[40]),float(row[42])])
        except ValueError:
           continue
```

However, when I use this code, it only returns the values to the list when every row of data is present. As mentioned, this only occurs for about 10% of the file. I am using the xy's to create a scatter plot at each point so cannot change to 0,0 as that will create a false data point. How do I alter the code so it returns the xy values when players data isn't removed.

Comment: as an aside, you could totally simplify your code: `list(map(float, row[2::2]))` and `list(map(float, row[3::2]))`

Comment: But, more fundamentally, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are there empty cells in the `P_2X` and  `P_2Y`  columns?

Comment: probably just do `.append([float(x) if x else float('nan') for x in row[2::2]])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you should consider just answering since all your comments are pieces of the solution.  Also wasn't aware `float('nan')` was a thing, that makes more sense than my `0.0` default.

Comment: Yes @ schwobaseggl. There are 21 players. each player will have data missing at any point in time.

Comment: @JeremyAlexander Then you should provide the information what you want do with the missing cells. What value should be put there?

Comment: Nothing. If I try to read the csv data with the missing values it returns a `Type Error: Can't convert string to float`. Therefore, I need to read the data that parses through each row and only returns the appropriate xy values.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own convert before the loop:

```
def convert_float(x);
    if x:            # equivalent to if x == ''
        return float(x)
    else:
        return 0.0   # or set the default value you expect to replace the missing data with.
```

In combination with [@juanpa.arrivillaga's excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556287/remove-values-when-reading-a-csv-and-return-to-a-list/48556460#comment-84108707), change the `visual.append` lines to these:

```
visual[0].append(list(map(convert_float, row[3::2]))
visual[1].append(list(map(convert_float, row[2::2]))
```

Also I'm not sure what your n+=1 line is supposed to do... if you merely wanted to skip the first row (headers), simply do this:

```
def convert_float(x);
    if x:
        return float(x)
    else:
        return 0.0

for i, row in enumerate(readCSV):
    if n > 0:
        visual[0].append(list(map(convert_float, row[3::2]))
        visual[1].append(list(map(convert_float, row[2::2]))
```

Comment: Sorry. I've altered the question but I can't use 0 as I need to make a scatter plot at each point in time. Basically, there are 21 player's XY at each time point. 3-4 will be missing 90% of the time. I can't replace those values with 0,0 as this will create a plot at this xy coordinate. I just need to read the file and return to a list without changing to another value.